# Spring Scheduler advantage of using cron expression vs fixed delay

Tags: java, spring, cron, scheduler

I have a method in Java8 project using Spring @Scheduled annotation to run at a fixed delay and call a deletion method.

Is there an advantage in performance or system stability in using cron expression rather than a delay string?

Adding the current implementation below:

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "${cleanup.unused.files.frequency}")
public void deleteUnusedFiles() throws IOException {
    LOGGER.info("Unused data files deletion started");
    recursiveDeleteFilesOlderThanNDays(unusedFileAgeThreshold, unusedFilesPath);
    LOGGER.info("Unused data files deletion completed");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Cron expression and fixedDelay is for providing customized scheduling options and have no impact on the performance as such. Improving **deleteUnusedFiles** method performance is the only option which would matter considerably for your application performance. I would prefer fixedDelay over cron if I can achieve what I want using fixedDelay.

Answer (score 0):

It may affect to your system stability. 
Think of a situation where you have 3 different ( its just a number ) instances of your application where you have @Scheduled annotation as well. And if you have deployed in 3 different servers which are located in considerably different geo locations ( for example one server in US, one in Singapore and one another in somewhere else ) if the scheduled task is being executed different time instances, there may be possibility of duplicating the work and possible error scenarios as well. (it depends on your Scheduler logic). But when it comes to Crons you can define the exact Timezone sort of things to start the Job which means irrespective which country your instance runs, the job will perform in each and every instance at a unique time. And more over if you think about crons in Kubernetes, ideally it maintains only one instance to do the job and if it fails only Kubernetes will create another scheduler instance for you. So there is a difference but still you can make a decision based on what you are really doing inside the scheduler.

Comment: Does cron expression waits for previous run to finish execution ?